# strategie to link multiple table to find "path"

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

I will ask intentionally a generic question

I have 12 table who represented different objects type.

from table 1 who represent the physical layer to the table 12 the most highest logical layer (like OSI model)

on each table you have the object and all informations relative to this object. additionally one column who represent the link to an upper layer let say "**usedBY**" (from a table you don't have a column with the link to a lower layer, in another words, the link can be check in one way lower to upper)

but the complex part for me is for gather/link infos together.

for example from table 1 the upper layer can be on table 2, on table 2 the object link to the table 1 , can be linked to next layer directly on table 4, on table 4 the object link to the table1 can be himself link to the table 6, from the table6 the object ends to table 12.
for an another object the path can be table 1 to 12 directly

object1 from Table1 **usedBy** object3445 on table 2 (where Table1.**usedBy** == Table2.id)

object3445 from table 2 **usedBy** object532, object432, object5215 on table4 (where Table2.**usedBy** == Table4.id)

object532 from table 4 **usedBy** object9831 on table 6 (where Table4.**usedBy** == Table6.id)
object432 from table 4 **usedBy** object 123 on table 7 (where Table4.**usedBy** == Table7.id)
object5215 from table 4 **usedBy** object 321 on table 8 (where Table4.**usedBy** == table8.id)

ect.. ect..

maybe with this example it would be clearer

I would like to create, maybe we can call this ... a link table  for each object the full path to table1 to table12.

I looking for a strategy for complete this goal, I am not used to database query.

****UPDATE****
The Impaler ask for a drawing for I hope a better explanation :)

[image: with the last 4 Layers]

**as you see every name can be use by any upper layer**

With cascading LEFT JOINT I can from table 12, find for each name in table 12 what is the previous layer

but after I am stuck

imagine from table 12 :

with LEFT JOIN I found for objectX :
NULL for TABLE11
NULL for TABLE10
ObjectY in TABLE9
NULL for [TABLE1-8]

after the found the first match I must start with TABLE9
and looking for in lower layer table where ObjectY is used

ect ect ...

I found this picture, seems to me, a good approach of path possibility.

[image: tree path]

Hoping that more clearer !

thanks in advance for your thought to explore !

PS: I am not English so please forgive my approximate English !

best regards

Comment: You don't need 12 tables. A single table will do. Is there a specific reason you need them in separate tables? Placing them in a single one will offer multiple easy solutions: 1) You can store them as a hierachy (using `parent_id`), or 2) You can store the nodes in one table and store the arcs in another table. Can you add a simple graph?

Comment: Yes you are right 'in fine' I don't need 12 tables. That why I try to gather information in the same table. I don't  have any choice because data  come from an API and give to me 12 csv file. My 12 table are feeded with those csv data. Sorry I don't understand "add a simple graph" do you mean for a better explanation, make a draw of data and potential link between them ?

Comment: Yes, if you could add a drawing (even text-based drawing) that could help understanding your question.

Comment: that is better ? :)